# Downloading a File with AFNetworking but Don't Know the Filetype or Name

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, afnetworking

So I am trying to download a file like this:

```
    NSString *acsmFileName = @"urllink.acsm";

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:licenceURL]];
    AFHTTPRequestOperation *downloader = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]initWithRequest:request];
    NSString *path = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:acsmFileName];
    downloader.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

    [downloader setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    }];
```

As can be seen, I had to mention the file name before downloading the file at all . Now, the file could be of a different extension and that's for me to determine after evaluating the extension after the download is completed.

Is there a way for me to do that?

Comment: Not sure if AFNetworking exposes this, but the http response header will contain the filename in `Content-Disposition` (if the server decides to send it to you). If that's missing, you just have to take the filename from the URL.

Comment: You can access in the success block `operation.response` and then `allHeaderFields` for accessing http headers

Comment: ^ Thanks for that, laucel. I have two types of file that can be there. One is an XML file with acsm extension and the other is an ePub file. The ACSM file shows as "application/vnd.adobe.adept+xml" in the "Content-Type" property of the HTTP header whereas, for the ePub, it says "binary". How to help this? Can it not get the name altogether from the server and save the file?

Comment: I am just wondering how does a browser get the name of the file while downloading?

Comment: I think that you have to listen to @Mike Weller suggestion

Comment: The HTTP Header doesn't have content-disposition property in the response object that I am listening to.

Comment: what about getting the filename from the URL? still credits to @Mike Weller

Comment: The URL doesn't have a filename at the end. It just gives the file to download after it has been called.

Comment: The server is probably returning an HTTP 302 redirect to a different URL to get the file